# How to find old deleted posts of my own?

Tags: support, feature-request, deleted-questions

I recently noted that one of my questions on meta.MSE has been deleted. Seems like it has been a victim of the [auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/243271) script. I usually keep improving the English my old posts. The same issue is with the main site. There might be some old questions there which are auto-deleted. I want to fix these questions. But  the *deleted recently posts* tab doesn't show old-deleted post. I usually save the link of the posts, which I feel might get deleted, in my meta posts. Because I thought that meta posts are not deleted; but this is not the case. So the question is,

> How can I find my old deleted posts on meta and main site?

If there is no way in SE to find the old deleted posts then I propose this as a feature request.

---

P.S: I've also asked a [related question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19687/103816) about the deletion of on-topic questions, with net score below 0, on meta.MSE.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible. Moderators are able to explicitly search for deleted posts, but otherwise there is no way (as far as I know) to find old, deleted posts. I guess you could search for an old data dump, use it to find your posts, and compare with your current posts, but that's a lot of work and not really guaranteed (I don't think there are regular archives of data.SE dumps).

Comment: Victim is a strong word.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not a native English speaker. I have to translate my thoughts in English...  ...Sometimes the translation becomes weird.

Comment: Now this seems to be [possible for 10k+ users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users). There is also this feature request on meta.SO: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). It is tagged (status-declined).

Comment: "Victim" is a good description of how it feels to have your content deleted.  Writing posts takes time.  Searching for answers about why you can't find your posts takes time.  Time is valuable.  Deleting posts creates victims.